# Getting wrong output using shell script

Tags: bash, shell, unix, syntax

I am learning shell scripting and this is the first script I am writing. However the output is not correct. What is wrong with the script?

```
echo Enter basic salary
read basic_sal
echo Basic salary is $basic_sal
da=`echo 0.4 \* basic_sal | bc`
echo Dearness allowance is $da
hra=`echo 0.2 \* basic_sal | bc`
echo House rent allowance is $hra
gross_sal=`echo basic_sal + da + hra | bc`
echo Gross salary is $gross_sal
```

**Output**

```
Enter basic salary
2000
Basic salary is 2000
Dearness allowance is 0
House rent allowance is 0
Gross salary is 0
```

Comment: Put a valid [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) and paste your script at https://shellcheck.net for validation/recommendation.

Comment: Missing a `$`: `echo 0.4 \* basic_sal` should be `echo 0.4 \* "$basic_sal"`, although it is probably cleaner to write `echo "0.4 * $basic_sal"`

Comment: And I would recommend to use `$(...)` instead of `\`...\``.

Comment: Good basic question! You included a small amount of code, the current output and it was clear what your expected output was. In the future, learn to piecemeal debug your code. You could have done `basic_sal=26000; echo 0.2 \* basic_sal | bc` and you would have immediately isolated the problem to the inputs to `bc`.